# How do I process two requests to the same address?

Tags: javascript, php, api

How can I process them so that I can use the data of both requests?
UI:

```
async function getSpecialties(){
  let res = await fetch ('http://server-npk-web-core/specialties');
  let specialties = await res.json();
  })
}
async function getSubjectsSpecial(){
  let res = await fetch ('http://server-npk-web-core/specialties');
  let subjectsSpecial = await res.json();
  })
}
```

BLL:
index.php

```
if($method === 'GET'){
  if($type === 'subjects'){
    getSubjects($pdo);
  } elseif($type === 'specialties'){
    getSpecialties($pdo);
    getSubjectsSpecial($pdo);
  }
```

specialties.php

```
function getSpecialties($pdo){
  $specialties = 'SELECT * FROM `specialties`';
  $stmt = $pdo -> query($specialties);
  while ($special = $stmt->fetch()){
    $specialtiesList[] = $special;
  }
  echo json_encode($specialtiesList);
}
function getSubjectsSpecial($pdo){
  $subjectsSpecial = 'SELECT `subjects`.`title` FROM `subjects` WHERE `id_specialties` = 2';
  $stmt = $pdo -> query($subjectsSpecial);
  while ($subjectSpecial = $stmt->fetch()){
    $subjectsSpecialList[] = $subjectSpecial;
  }
  echo json_encode($subjectsSpecialList);
}
```

P.S. Don't beat me with sticks, I'm learning on my own -_-

Comment: Create another async function and await both of the functions provided?

Comment: Both requests current look identical. Use a querystring parameter for each request so that the backend script can call the respective function and send the appropriate response

Answer (score 0):

To use the same `endpoint`to process two or more different requests you need to provide the means by which the server can choose the appropriate actions to take. As your `fetch` requests are done using `GET` you can provide a querystring parameter which is then used server-side to fork program logic. For example:

```
<?php

    //-------------------------------
    //server-npk-web-core/specialties
    //-------------------------------
    
    
    function getSpecialties($pdo){
      $specialties = 'SELECT * FROM `specialties`';
      $stmt = $pdo -> query($specialties);
      while ($special = $stmt->fetch()){
        $specialtiesList[] = $special;
      }
      echo json_encode($specialtiesList);
    }
    
    function getSubjectsSpecial($pdo){
      $subjectsSpecial = 'SELECT `subjects`.`title` FROM `subjects` WHERE `id_specialties` = 2';
      $stmt = $pdo -> query($subjectsSpecial);
      while ($subjectSpecial = $stmt->fetch()){
        $subjectsSpecialList[] = $subjectSpecial;
      }
      echo json_encode($subjectsSpecialList);
    }
    
    
    
    
    if( !empty( $_GET['action'] ) ){
    
        switch( $_GET['action'] ){
            case 'specialties':
                getSpecialties($pdo)
            break;
            case 'subjectsspecial':
                getSubjectsSpecial( $pdo );
            break;
            default:
                echo 'Error';
            break;
        }
        
    }
?>
```

And the modified `fetch` requests with new querystring parameter

```
<script>
    async function getSpecialties(){
      let res = await fetch ('http://server-npk-web-core/specialties?action=specialties');
      let specialties = await res.json();
      })
    };
    async function getSubjectsSpecial(){
      let res = await fetch ('http://server-npk-web-core/specialties?action=subjectsspecial');
      let subjectsSpecial = await res.json();
      })
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I did it according to your advice, but a lot of errors pop up this way

https://disk.yandex.ru/i/Dh2kMOIq0BRJpQ

Comment: The link you gave does not work - or if it does I cannot understand what is said